# C++ object and namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Looking at some C++ code and encountered this:

```
response<std::string> client::send_raw(const std::string& request...)
```

I am confused about `response` --is it an object or namespace? What is `client::send_raw`? Where is the function name?

Comment: Could be a static member function for the `client` class. Or maybe this code is the definition of `client::send_raw()`

Comment: `response` is a template, with specialization `std::string` in this case. The full type of the function's return value is `response<std::string>`. The function name is `send_raw` and is a member of the `client` class or namespace. So `client::send_raw` is its fully-qualified name.

Comment: The questions you are asking can be answered by taking some time to understand the fundamentals of the language from a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It will be better to learn the language that way instead of getting answers to these specific questions.

Comment: Thank you. I've studied the basics of C++ but this was new to me. @CoryKramer that was super helpful

Answer (score 0):

> "`response` is a template, with specialization `std::string` in this case. The full type of the function's return value is `response<std::string>`. The function name is `send_raw` and is a member of the `client` class or namespace. So `client::send_raw` is its fully-qualified name."
>
> ~CoryKramer